# TypeError: 'MovieWriterRegistry' object is not an iterator

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to create an animation of a sin wave using the [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) function from matplotlib, but it keeps throwing an error. I am a little new to it, but I read that there is a bug in the latest version? Anyone that can help me is welcome.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 4), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)


anim.save('sine_wave.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

Comment: Hi @Parvfect, can you clarify your question? What is the error you receive and at what line of the code do you receive it?

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'MovieWriterRegistry' object is not an iterator. There is no specific line that causes it, it shows me an error in the matplotlib.animate file. It gets called by the last line of the code though.

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16965) . You might have to update your version of matplotlib

Comment: Hi can you include an copy of the error traceback in your question please? Like this we can see exactly what caused the error.